# How to observeOn the calling thread in java rx?

Tags: rx-java, android-syncadapter, rx-android

is there anyway to tell java rx to use the current thread in the observeOn function? I am writing code for the android syncadapter and I want the results be observed in the sync adapter thread and not in the main thread.

An example network call with Retrofit + RX Java looks something like that:

```
MyRetrofitApi.getInstance().getObjects()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(<current_thread>)
.subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
    //do stuff on the sync adapter thread

}
```

I tried using using

```
...
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.handlerThread(new Handler(Looper.myLooper())))
...
```

which is the same way android rx creates the scheduler for the main thread but doesn't work anymore as soon as I substitute `Looper.myLooper()` for `Looper.getMainLooper()`.

I could use the Schedulers.newThread() but as its complex syncing code with a lot of server calls I would be constantly creating a new thread just to fire new network calls that again create new threads to to launch more network calls. Is there a way to do this? Or is my approach itself completly wrong?

Comment: This is a bit speculative, so I am not posting this as an answer: From version 2.0-beta2 on, Retrofit does not put the network request on a different thread anymore - see here: https://github.com/square/retrofit/commit/38ce2bee70342ac1ab08115d74802d3a54d85511 So, if you are using a current version of Retrofit you should be able to just skip the `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` altogether and just stay on the sync adapter thread the whole time. Or did I misunderstand your question and you do want to create new threads but they should just all return to the thread you started from?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try Using `Schedulers.immediate()`

```
MyRetrofitApi.getInstance().getObjects()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
.subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
    //do stuff on the sync adapter thread

}
```

Its description says: `Creates and returns a Scheduler that executes work immediately on the current thread.`

**NOTE:**
I think it is okay to keep all the work on the SyncAdapter's thread because it is already using a different thread

Comment: Schedulers.immediate() not working for me. I need observe on GlThread but it observe on thread from subscribeOn. What could be the reason?

Comment: @DmitriyPuchkov what is the order of your `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` functions?

Comment: The order is the same as you write. I resolve my problem by create custom executor that post runnables to GLThread.

Comment: @DmitriyPuchkov was your `GLThread` the current one? The solution I wrote worked for me.

Comment: no Schedulers.immediate() on RxJava2, anything new?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I just found this in the wiki at: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid#observing-on-arbitrary-threads

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler(); // bound to this thread
        Observable.just("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(HandlerScheduler.from(handler))
                .subscribe(/* an Observer */)

        // perform work, ...
    }
}, "custom-thread-1").start();
```

I think this should work for your case, too - except the creation of a new Thread, of course... So just:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); // bound to this thread
MyRetrofitApi.getInstance().getObjects()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(HandlerScheduler.from(handler))
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
        //do stuff on the sync adapter thread

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick repy. I upgraded rx android (I had used an older version) and tried the example. Unfortunately it didn't work, but I created some tests and found out the that onNext() is called but the Subscriber doesn't receive it. Only after adding Looper.loop() at the end it seem to work (which is an infite loop that processes the message). Even the exact same example tells me I need to use Looper.prepare() before creating the Handler. Maybe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong or it might be an issues with android rx itself?

Comment: I am afraid I cannot tell you what's going wrong here... let's see what others have to say...

Comment: @tiqz `found out the that onNext() is called but the Subscriber doesn't receive it` the onNext is a Subscriber's method so what you write is a bit strange for me. In theory david's answer should be fine. I would recommend you post more detailed stuff of what you are trying in order we can help you.